# Функция swith case в цикле

Tags: php

Всем доброго времени суток.

Есть табличка, которая выводится в цикле. В одной из ячеек волшебная фраза "%s" которая, само собой равна определенной переменной. (Число от 0 до 9.)

Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы вместо значения на месте "%s" было: если "%s" = 1, то слово 1, если "%s" = 2, то слово 2...

p.s. Пробовал swith case. То ли я не правильно написал, то ли условие в цикле не сработало.

Comment: Чего-то я не понимаю ... а если "%s" = 1, то это разве не есть то, что вам нужно... Разве что может нужно поменять s на i - если возникают проблемы...

Comment: Цикл с "%s" работает без сбоев. Ну, допустим, "%s" = 1, то слово "один", "%s" = 2, то слово "два"...

Comment: Очень тяжело понять, что вам нужно. Приведите пример исходного массива и конечного результата.
Больше всего мне непонятна фраза:

> В одной из ячеек волшебная фраза "%s" которая, само собой равна определенной переменной. (Число от 0 до 9.)

Как может фраза, пусть и волшебная(!), быть равной какой-то переменной, которая на самом деле число?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно создать массив, array(0 => 'ноль', 1 => 'один'...) и подставлять array[$s], s - то, что вы подставляете в "%s".

Comment: Создал массив $s[]...
array[$s] - сработало, но вместо значений фраза array[Array]
$s[%s] - не сработало